# Spring-MVC bean class cannot be found

Tags: java, ant, spring-mvc

In my build.xml, I set the attribute `scr.dir`:

```
<property name="src.dir" value="${backend.dir}/java-src/catw/src"/>
```

My dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<bean name="/welcome.htm" class="com.bamboo.catW3.business.impl.WelcomeController"/>
```

My view WEB-INF/jsp:

```
welcome.jsp
```

My controller:

```
com.bamboo.catW3.business.impl.WelcomeController.java
```

I run the project and show me this message:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException:
Cannot find class [com.bamboo.catW3.business.impl.WelcomeController] for bean
with name '/welcome.htm' defined in ServletContext resource
[/WEB-INF/branch_try_htmlModulo-servlet.xml]; nested exception is
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.bamboo.catW3.business.impl.WelcomeController
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1076)
```

I don't know how to fix this error, can anyone help me please?

Comment: Does the error is shown when you compile the project, or when you run your application?

Comment: Well, that is the contain my controller in WEB-INF/classes

C:\Archivos de programa\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.5\webapps\branch_try_htmlModulo1\war\WEB-INF\classes\com\bamboo\catW3\business\impl\WelcomeController.java

Comment: @josé You should see a WelcomeController.class there, not a WelcomeController.java

Comment: @Thierry-Dimitri Roy you have absolutely right, i see a WelcomeController.class but continues show me that error

Comment: I've got it, thank you all for your advice

Answer (score 1):

In your build, your output directory is not pointing to the correct location (as specified by the `destdir` attribute. A `ClassNotFoundException` means that the application looks for the compiled WelcomeController, but cannot find it. Usually web application expects compiled class files to be under:

```
/WEB-INF/classes
```

So make sure that you build output points to this directory. After a successful build, you should see:

```
/WEB-INF/classes/com/bamboo/catW3/business/impl/WelcomeController.class
```

Comment: but in my WEB-INF/Classes generate it, that is the contain my controller in WEB-INF/classes C:\Archivos de programa\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.5\webapps\branch_try_htmlModulo1\war\WEB-INF\classes\com\bamboo\catW3\business\impl\WelcomeController.java

Comment: @josé: dont know if this spelling matters, your webapp is *branch_try_htmlModulo1* but your spring file is */WEB-INF/branch_try_htmlModulo-servlet.xml*. Is it looking under the correct WEB-INF for the class?

Answer (score 0):

Double check that the destdir attribute of your  tag (or  tag) in your ant build script is set to the correct class directory for your application server (ie: Tomcat). You could also just look for the class file in your build directory.

Comment: <target name="build" description="Compile main source tree java files">
        <mkdir dir="${build.dir}"/>
        <javac destdir="${build.dir}" source="1.5" target="1.5" debug="true"
               deprecation="false" optimize="false" failonerror="true">
           <src path="${src.dir}"/>
            <classpath refid="master-classpath"/>
        </javac>
    </target>

Comment: the destdir =$(build.dir)

 <property name="build.dir" value="${web.dir}/WEB-INF/classes"/>

Answer (score 0):

May be many of u r getting problem with springhelloworld project.I have recently faced that problem as from eclipse when i am running it,it's working fine..but from browser it is showing error like class not found exception.So,I have found solution for that...it is a problem of class file....

Solution:

Just put your classes folder from build/classes to your WEB-INF directory...and your problem will be solved...

I hope this will help you...